# Img width 100% : height 110%

Tags: html, image

I am having this issue, I want an image in html to have 100% width of it's parent div but also 110% height. It is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. http://jsfiddle.net/548a0kjf/1

Comment: please provide us with some code or perhaps a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lrzc9L1/ sry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's the problem with your code - because you didn't show it -, but here's an example of code for an image with 100% width of it's parent div but also 110% height that might help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            #img-wrapper { border: 5px solid #000; width: 50%; height: 50%; }
            #img { display: block; width: 100%; height: 110%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="img-wrapper">
            <img id="img" src="https://www.helpkidscode.com/pub/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/oskay-hello-world-toast.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- If the image is not occupying the whole element parent inside, add a `display: block` to the element with the image.
- If the element parent of the image does not seem to have the correct height and the height value is a percentage, check its element parent height (in the example, I set the html and body height values to feel the screen).

Comment: can u see the url pls i gave in a comment above.

Comment: I think I solved it: [http://jsfiddle.net/s8rtrfjx/](http://jsfiddle.net/s8rtrfjx/)

Comment: You needed to add an explicit height value in the image parent element (I added the <code>height: 100%;</code>), otherwise the browser won't "know" to what height the percentage is related and will just make the image height and parent element inner height the same.